# Увеличение стороны прямоугольника в Java

Tags: java

Есть задание:

```
public void enlarge(int nx, int ny)
```

Увеличивает стороны Rectangle в (nx, ny) раз при сохранении координат левой верхней вершины.

Есть тестовый класс для проверки:

```
public class TestRectangle {   
    @Test
    public void testEnlargeRectangle() {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40);
        rect.enlarge(3, 5);
        assertEquals(10, rect.getTopLeft().getX());
        assertEquals(20, rect.getTopLeft().getY());
        assertEquals(70, rect.getBottomRight().getX());
        assertEquals(120, rect.getBottomRight().getY());
    }
}
```

Я чесно не до конца понимаю задание. Мне нужно левую верхнюю вершину оставить на месте и просто сдвинуть правый нижний угол прямоугольника, и как следствие он растянется. Как разобраться?

Comment: А что, фразу "Увеличивает стороны Rectangle в (nx, ny) раз при сохранении координат левой верхней вершины" можно понять разными способами?

Answer (score 1):

1. Вычисляете ширину приямоугольника (правая сторона - левая сторона)
2. Увеличиваете ширину в N раз
3. Обновляете правую сторону (левая сторона + новая ширина)

Повторяете для высоты.